# How to display math formulas in buttons of Android apps?

Tags: java, android, mathjax

I'm already aware that [Nishant Pathak's MathView](https://github.com/Nishant-Pathak/MathView), an extension of WebView, can be used in displaying math formulas in Android apps. However what I want is more than that using  for my app. Right now I also would like to have math formulas appear in buttons. Can this happen?

Comment: What did you try so far? please share your efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Widget.Button"
```

to the `MathView`. This should not change the functionality of the view, but make it appear as if it was a button.